# How to create dataframe from JSON in another dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm new to spark and have been struggling how I can manipulate the data this way. Suppose I have a dataframe which has two columns, each containing JSON data. I want to make each of the keys in the JSON into columns in one single dataframe.

For example, if I had the following dataframe:

```
|           key|         value|
+--------------+--------------+
|{"foo": "bar"}|{"baz": "qux"}|
```

Then the resulting dataframe would look like this.

```
|   foo|   baz|
+------+------+
|   bar|   qux|
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just assuming your input data as parquet format:

1. Create InputRDD from your input location
2. Transform InputRDD into dataframe using "toDf" function
3. Create Two schema structures for both **Key** column and **Value** columns
4. Transform to new dataframe by adding new columns by sending your jsontype columns as input argument to **from_json** function along with schema structure

example:

```
val Sampledata_df = spark.read.parquet("path/to/input.parquet")  


val key_Json_Schema = StructType(Seq( 
                                   StructField("foo", StringType, true)
                                ))
val value_Json_Schema = StructType(Seq(
                                  StructField("baz", StringType, true) 
                                ))   


val Parsed_df = Sampledata_df
               .withColumn("parsed_key", from_json(col("key"), key_Json_Schema))
               .withColumn("pased_value", from_json(col("value"), value_Json_Schema))


val Output_df = Parsed_df
                .withColumn("output_key", $"parsed_key.foo")
                .withColumn("output_value", $"pased_value.baz")
                .select($"output_key",$"output_value")
```